# Why does Google's IAB code cause me errors

Tags: in-app-billing

I am following this guide to set up in app billing in my app but while following the Google made guide I keep getting unhandled exception errors from this

```
Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, 
   getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);
```

and

```
int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
if (response == 0) {
   ArrayList<String> responseList
      = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

   for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
      JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
      String sku = object.getString("productId");
      String price = object.getString("price");
      if (sku.equals("premiumUpgrade")) mPremiumUpgradePrice = price;
      else if (sku.equals("gas")) mGasPrice = price;
   }
}
```

this code.

Guide is : http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#QueryDetails

Why does a Google made guide cause these problems, surely their own instructions should not cause errors?